# SQL convert text to date and minus 1day ago query

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I'm trying to convert a text field to date and only pull back records that have a date of yesterday but getting zero records back. I've converted the text to date part but can't get the where clause working and not sure where I'm going wrong.

SQL Query:

```
SELECT
REQUEST_DATE,
convert(varchar, REQUEST_DATE ,101) as REQUEST_DATE1
FROM  temp
Where convert(varchar, REQUEST_DATE ,101) > DATEADD(DAY,-1,getdate())
```

Comment: Did you mean to post this in a Salesforce specific forum? This looks like it belongs elsewhere in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Yes i'm using the SQL query in SFMC

Comment: Add the tag [marketing-cloud] next time, more people will see your question that way. Would have added with the first edit, but I was unsure about where you were running the query from.

Comment: You have to convert it to datetime type: CONVERT(datetime, '2017-08-25')

Comment: What's the format of your date string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want rows from yesterday, you can do something like this:

```
select
request_date,
convert(date, request_date) as request_date1
from temp
where convert(date, request_date) >= convert(date, getdate()-1)
and convert(date, request_date) < convert(date, getdate())
```

If your `request_date` is actually a date datatype in SFMC, then you can simplify it like this:

```
select
request_date
from temp
where request_date >= convert(date, getdate()-1)
and request_date < convert(date, getdate())
```